# How to sort date strings (format example: 2014 7 23) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

In JavaScript I'm trying to sort an array of objects, each having a date, by date, but I ran into an obstacle. Also the date's are input from 3 dropdown boxes on a site, so I just want 3 numbers. This means I cannot use JavaScript's Date() object, since it also adds a time, timezone and writes month names in letters etc.

Example:
I added 5 objects into an array. I have tried using the JavaScript sort function, this one to be specific:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.date == b.date){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a.date < b.date){
        return 1;
    } 
     else {
        return -1;
    }
})
```

However, this only sorts by year.

So If I add:
2014 7 12
2017 8 16
2017 4 14
2017 1 31
2017 2 26

I get:
2014 7 12
2017 2 26
2017 8 16
2017 1 31
2017 4 14

This is the constructor I use to make different Label objects.

```
function Label(name, date, type) {
this.name = name;
this.date = date;
this.type = type;
```

}

```
var a = new Label("name1", "2016 5 16", 5);
var b = new Label("name2", "2016 7 20", 3);
var c = new Label("name3", "2016 3 15", 2);
```

My date attributes are just 3 numbers in a string. So I tried rewriting the sort function to this:

```
    array.sort(function(a,b){
        a = a.date.split(" ");
        b = b.date.split(" ");
        if(a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1] && a[2] === a[2]){
            return 0;
        }
        else if ((a[0] > b[0]) || (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] > b[1]) || (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === b[1] && a[2] > b[2])){
            return -1;
        } 
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

I.e. I tried to use the .split function to seperate the 3 numbers, which are then stored in an array. Date a is then assigned the array with 3 numbers, as is date b. Then I check if the values in both arrays are equal, if so, return 0 (do nothing).
If the year in array a is bigger than year in array b, move it down 1 space in the output array.
If the year is equal, then check the month. If the month is bigger in a than in b, move a down 1 space in the output array.
Etc.

However this doesn't happen. It basically gives me the same output, only sorting by year but ignoring month and day.

I have checked several similar StackOverflow questions, but most of them use the Date() object.
I specifically need the format "number number number".

Why doesn't my function work and how might I make it work?

EDIT: made my post a bit clearer with examples of dates and my constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the date format is always the same as you're already splitting etc. and what you should do is use date objects and compare them instead

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    var arr1 = a.date.split(" ");
    var arr2 = b.date.split(" ");

    var time1 = new Date(arr1[0], arr1[1]-1, arr1[2]); // year, month, day
    var time2 = new Date(arr2[0], arr2[1]-1, arr2[2]);

    return time1 - time2;
});
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the `getTime` method of the `Date` object to correctly get the millisecond-timestamp value?

Comment: Also this seems pretty inefficient for sorting code

Comment: You can compare date objects directly, and it might not be very efficient, but the strings must be converted to date objects to properly compare them.

Comment: @adeneo Hmm I see but why do you put a -1 here : arr1[1]-1, arr2[1]-1 and not at year and day?

Comment: Because in javascript months are zero based.

Comment: (Meaning they go from 0-11 not 1-12) That's so they can be easily cross-referenced with an array of month names to be more language independent.

Comment: Aha I see, okay that helps a lot thanks :) So you "transform" the date attributes of my Label objects to Date() objects, just to facilitate the sorting process, but the actual content of the "date" attributes of the Label objects remains untouched, that about right?

Comment: Anyway thanks guys. Johnathan your answer I see is correct aswell and possibly more efficient? But adeneo's code is easier to understand for newbies like me :)

Answer (score 0):

DO use javascript's date object and do the following for sorting:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date.getTime()-b.date.getTime();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, lets just sort a few things out.

- Javascript `Date` objects are stored as the number of milliseconds since datum, when you output them to a string they may well have milliseconds, timezone information etc but thats got nothing to do with their internals.
- Your sort function is an overly complex way of just doing `a.date - b.date`

Therefore what you want to do is have the properties as actual `Date` objects, and use the sort function

```
var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  a.date - b.date;
});
```