# Javascript - Sort array of objects by date then by time

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have the following array:

```
[{id: 1, value : "value1", date: "2018-08-08", time: "15:27:17"},
{id: 2, value : "value2", date: "2018-08-09", time: "12:27:17"},
{id: 3, value : "value3", date: "2018-08-10", time: "17:27:17"},
{id: 4, value : "value4", date: "2018-08-11", time: "10:27:17"}]
```

How can I go about sorting the array from earliest to latest or vice versa?

I tried sorting by date, but sorting it by time swaps the order of record id 4 to id 3, because it has an earlier time value than record 3, but is technically by definition, later.

Given this array and json structure, how do I sort the array to take both fields (`date` and `time`) into consideration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort date strings (format exmaple: 2014 7 23) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193232/how-to-sort-date-strings-format-exmaple-2014-7-23-in-javascript)

Comment: hello, the answer does not seem to consider a 2nd property time that is separate from date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort by the difference in the `date`s, and if there is no difference, sort by the difference in the `time`s, in a single `.sort` function:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, value : "value1", date: "2018-08-08", time: "15:27:17"},
{id: 2, value : "value2", date: "2018-08-09", time: "12:27:17"},
{id: 3, value : "value3", date: "2018-08-10", time: "17:27:17"},
{id: 4, value : "value4", date: "2018-08-10", time: "01:27:17"},
{id: 5, value : "value5", date: "2018-08-10", time: "09:27:17"},
{id: 6, value : "value6", date: "2018-08-10", time: "23:27:17"},
{id: 7, value : "value7", date: "2018-08-10", time: "16:27:17"},
{id: 8, value : "value8", date: "2018-08-11", time: "10:27:17"}
];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date) || a.time.localeCompare(b.time));
console.log(arr);
```

The difference in dates will be returned, except if they're the same, in which case the `localCompare` will come out to `0`, and the difference in times will be returned instead.

To sort to descending instead, just switch the `a`s and `b`s:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, value : "value1", date: "2018-08-08", time: "15:27:17"},
{id: 2, value : "value2", date: "2018-08-09", time: "12:27:17"},
{id: 3, value : "value3", date: "2018-08-10", time: "17:27:17"},
{id: 4, value : "value4", date: "2018-08-10", time: "01:27:17"},
{id: 5, value : "value5", date: "2018-08-10", time: "09:27:17"},
{id: 6, value : "value6", date: "2018-08-10", time: "23:27:17"},
{id: 7, value : "value7", date: "2018-08-10", time: "16:27:17"},
{id: 8, value : "value8", date: "2018-08-11", time: "10:27:17"}
];

arr.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date) || b.time.localeCompare(a.time));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this sorts in ascending order, how do i alternate between ascending and descending?