# React toggle for sorting doesn't work. Individual functions work

Tags: reactjs

I created two buttons for sorting the year field of a list ascending and descending. They work perfectly. And then I want to replace the buttons with one toggle button to change between ascending and descending. It doesn't work. My codes below. Would someone please advise? Thank you very much.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Button} from "reactstrap";

const MovieList = () => {    

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [sort, setSort] = useState(true)

    // Sort by Year
    // I need to use localeCompare because the year is string
  const sortByYearDesc = () => {
    const sorted = [...movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return b.year.localeCompare(a.year);
    });
    setMovies(sorted);
  }
  
  const sortByYearAsc = () => {
    const sorted = [...movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return a.year.localeCompare(b.year);
    });
    setMovies(sorted);
  }

  const toggleSort = () => {
    setSort(!sort)
    return sort ? sortByYearAsc  :  sortByYearDesc

  }

    return (
      
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Movies</h1>
        <hr />
        <div>
          <Button onClick={toggleSort} color="info">{sort ? "Sort by Desc" : "Sort by Asc"}</Button>
        </div>
            
      <div>
        <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Film Name</th>
              <th>Oscar Winner</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                {movies.map(movie => (
                <tr key={movie.id}>
                <td>{movie.year}</td>
                <td>{movie.filmName}</td>
                <td>{movie.winner}</td>
                <td>{movie.country}</td>
            </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
          </table>
          
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default MovieList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `sortByYearAsc` and `sortByYearDesc` are functions, you need to execute them in the `toggleSort` function.

e.g. the `updated code` will be

```
const toggleSort = () => {
  setSort(prevSort => !prevSort)
  !sort ? sortByYearAsc()  :  sortByYearDesc() // since the state is not updated yet.
}
```

### Option 2

You can also use the `useEffect` hook, whenever the `sort` updates, that `useEffect` will execute the relevant function.

Only update the state in `toggleSort`

```
const toggleSort = () => {
  setSort(prevSort => !prevSort)
}
```

then use the `useEffect` based on the `sort` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  sort ? sortByYearAsc()  :  sortByYearDesc()
}, [sort])
```

Comment: Thanks but both do not work.

Comment: Alright. Does the functions are not being executed or sorting not working?

Comment: I tried to console log something inside the sortByYearAsc and sortByYearDesc functions. Somethings did print out. So the two functions are executed. But no sorting effect.

Comment: Is it possible to share the `movies` array or a couple of objects. Otherwise, you can look into sorting function [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757994/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-by-date-then-by-time) or [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my problem. Your solution should work.