# What's wrong on order these data by a, than by b, than by c conditions?

Tags: javascript, sorting

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/6wxe49um/) my snippet:

```
let arr = 
[
  {
    side: "SELL",
    completed: true,
    lastUpdate: "2021-06-21 21:47:09"
  },
  {
    side: "BUY",
    completed: true,
    lastUpdate: "2022-06-21 21:47:09"
  },
  {
    side: "BUY",
    completed: false,
    lastUpdate: "2020-06-21 21:47:09"
  },
  {
    side: "SELL",
    completed: true,
    lastUpdate: "2023-06-21 21:47:09"
  },
  {
    side: "BUY",
    completed: true,
    lastUpdate: "2019-06-21 21:47:09"
  }
];

arr.sort(function (a, b) { return 
  a.side.toString().localeCompare(b.side.toString()) || 
  a.completed.toString().localeCompare(b.completed.toString() || 
  b.lastUpdate.toString().localeCompare(a.lastUpdate.toString())) });

console.log(arr)
```

which should:

```
- order by side asc (i.e. first BUY, then SELL)
- then order by completed asc (i.e. first false, then true)
- then by date desc
```

But it doesn't.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.side.toString().localeCompare(b.side.toString()) || 
                  a.completed - b.completed || new Date(b.lastUpdate) - new Date(a.lastUpdate))
```

You need to convert the `lastUpdate` property to a date first

Output:
[image]

Comment: Missed that in my answer. As it is now, they're just sorting the dates alphabetically. Didn't notice it since all the `lastUpdate` have the same value. Good catch!

Comment: Why with date work and with localeCompare doesnt?

Comment: This may explain why - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193330/2570277

Comment: @Nick can't use it on TypeScript env; it says "TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type."

Comment: EDIT: using .getTime() seems to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it works for me:

Here's a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-antonelli-bk3j9t?file=/src/App.js

Could it be that your sort function has a return statement on it's own line, and therefore returns undefined?

EDIT: That seems to be the case, didn't notice your fiddle but if you update it to:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return (a.side.toString().localeCompare(b.side.toString()) || a.completed.toString().localeCompare(b.completed.toString() || b.lastUpdate.toString().localeCompare(a.lastUpdate.toString()))) });
```

It looks like it updates the sorting order to the one you describe.